# Am I creating a global variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm creating a function that tests Angular filters using Jasmine. The specs are ran by Karma. The idea is to pass a module and filter name, with an array of tests to be performed on it. Every  element of that array has a description, an input value and an expected result. But it also could contain a testSteps function for tests that are not as simple as passing an input value and expecting an exact value. The function I'm making is meant to create the corresponding Jasmine describe and it blocks for the tests, and it's inside a global variable defined like this:

```
var $uite = {
    testFilter : function(filterName, moduleName, tests) {
        this.filterObject = null;
        this.isDefined = function(vble) {
            return typeof (vble) != 'undefined';
        }
        describe('FILTER: ' + filterName, function() {

            beforeEach(module(moduleName));
            beforeEach(inject(function($filter) {
                filterObject = $filter(filterName);
            }));

            for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
                var test = tests[i];
                it(test.it, function() {
                    if (typeof (test.forInputValue) != 'undefined') {
                        var result = filterObject(test.forInputValue);
                        expect(result).toEqual(test.resultShouldBe);
                    } else if (typeof (test.testSteps) != 'undefined') {
                        test.testSteps();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code for my tests is:

```
$uite.testFilter('nameFilter', 'app', [ {
    it : 'gets male gender from a name ending in O',
    forInputValue : 'Pedro',
    resultShouldBe : 'el tal Pedro'
}, {
    it : 'gets female gender from a name ending in A',
    forInputValue : 'Carolina',
    resultShouldBe : 'la tal Carolina'
}, {
    it : 'transforms Lina into la tal Lina',
    testSteps : function() {
        var result = filterObject('Lina');
        expect(result).toEqual('la tal Lina');
    }
} ]);
```

It works just fine but just for curiosity and because I'm avoiding creating unnecesary global variables, I wrote the following test just after them:

```
describe('some test',function(){
    it('works',function(){
        expect(typeof(filterObject)).toEqual('undefined');
    });
});
```

Which fails because type of filterObject is function. If my filterObject is defined inside the $uite object and was not (was it?) declared implicitly, then why is it accessible from another describe/it block set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question: *Am I creating a global variable?*

## TL;DR

yes

## Full answer

It is global. You're making it global here:

```
filterObject = $filter(filterName);
```

If you don't put `var` before that, and you're not using strict mode (e.g. `use strict;`), then it will be a global.

If you want it to refer to `this`, you need to use `this` everywhere:

```
beforeEach(inject.call(this, function($filter) {
    this.filterObject = $filter(filterName);
}.bind(this)));
```

Or something like that. Alternatively, you can declare `var _this = this`:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($filter) {
    _this.filterObject = $filter(filterName);
}));
```

Everywhere else throughout your code, you'll need to refer to it as `this.filterObject`.

FYI, a note about [strict mode (article on MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (I always suggest using it, because it catches accidental globals) from the section "Converting mistakes into errors":

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global variables.

Additional references:

1. [Function.prototype.bind on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
2. [Function.prototype.call on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

P.S. Looks like you're coming from a Java background. When using objects, defining `this.<whatever>` and then trying to refer to it as simply `<whatever>` won't work in JavaScript like you'd expect it to work in Java.

## Edit

To access `filterObject` in your third test, do this:

```
// ... in $suite
} else if (typeof (test.testSteps) != 'undefined') {
    // make this.filterObject available as a parameter
    test.testSteps(this.filterObject);
}

// then in your test definition...

}, {
    it : 'transforms Lina into la tal Lina',
    testSteps : function(filterObject) {  // this line is important
        var result = filterObject('Lina');
        expect(result).toEqual('la tal Lina');
    }
} ]);
```

Comment: If I refer to it always with this. the third test (the one with testSteps) fails because "The object does not accept the filterObject property". If I remove the this keyword only from the testSteps function then "filterObject is not defined". Is there a way of creating a testSteps function that could access that filterObject that I inject on the describe/it blocks?

Comment: @PedroOtero great question. I've edited my answer with a solution to that.

Comment: I had tried that and worked but I thought it was redundant since there is a filterName parameter with which I'm retrieving the filter. Should I just edit this whole question or ask a new more specific one?

Comment: @PedroOtero not quite sure what you're asking. But to answer your current question, yes, you are creating a global variable.

Comment: @PedroOtero if editing your question would change the intent of your question, then it should be a new question on StackOverflow